# How do I get my output from a program on to a csv file using bash?

Tags: python-3.x, bash, export-to-csv

How do I get my output from a program on to a csv file using bash? It kept overwriting when I send the output of the program.

```
outfile="gremlin_pop"$low_pop"-"$hi_pop".csv"
echo "Initial Population,Good Gremlins,Bad Gremlins" > $outfile

for p in `seq $low_pop $step_pop $hi_pop`;
do
    echo "Experiment: " $p
    python3 gremlinSim.py $p 
done
```

My csv file should look like this,

```
Initial Population,Good Gremlins,Bad Gremlins
10,10,0
20,20,0
30,30,4
40,50,4
50,61,4
```

The output from the program,

```
Experiment:  10
10 10 0
Experiment:  20 
20 20 0
Experiment:  30
30 30 4
Experiment:  40
40 50 4
Experiment:  50
50 61 4
```

Comment: Since you ask it explicitly to overwrite (`>`), of course it overwrites. If you append (`>>`), it appends, However, since you seem to create a CSV with column header, don't forget that if you simply switch from overwriting to appending, you would end up with new CSV headers in the middle of your CSV file.

Comment: It seems that the output depends on file germLinSim.py.
It would be helpful if you add the code of germLinSim.py so that the readers would be able to see how it does the processing and will be able to suggest and answer.

Answer (score 2):

> It kept overwriting when I send the output of the program.

This is cause you use `>` to create/overwrite a file, instead of `>>` to add text to an file.
You should also get rid of the `echo` statements when you add output to that `$outfile`. Or ...

```
echo "Initial Population,Good Gremlins,Bad Gremlins" >> "$outfile"
echo "Experiment: ${p}" >> "$outfile"
```

Not sure why you wont edit the python script to behave like you want. Anyway, to change the output of that script you could use `tr`.

```
python3 gremlinSim.py $p | tr '[:blank:]' ',' >> "$outfile"
```

Output:

```
10,10,0
20,20,0
30,30,4
40,50,4
50,61,4
```

The `[:blank:]` represent ***spaces*** and ***tabstop*** while the `,` will be used as replacement.